# Title about @Protocol and categories

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know about categories and Protocol with example for objective-c

Comment: Um, what? I'm having a really hard time understanding what your **question** is.

Comment: yeah u will surely get know .. best of luck :)

Comment: Read some basic (and must-read!) docs at first, hard to advice something better. If something won't be clear ask more specific questions then

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protocol versus Category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360992/protocol-versus-category)

Answer (score 2):

For a start try relevant sections in "Introduction to Objective-C language":

- [Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1)
- [Categories and extensions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1)