# How do protocols in Objective C work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-c - Purpose of categories and protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394915/objective-c-purpose-of-categories-and-protocols)

Can anyone justify @protocol mechanism of Objective C in simple words.
Like,

1. Defining protocol
2. Implementing protocol
3. Other alternatives of protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a good introduction on protocols at [Apple's developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html), as well as on [WikiBooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Objective-C_Programming/in_depth#Protocols).