# Difference between Object and Category?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa

Difference between subclass and category? Which place used effectively in both items?And difference between category and protocol? Need real time example.

Thanks

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360992/protocol-versus-category

Comment: You need to read a Objective-C for beginners book. It will tell you everything under the chapter called "Categories".

Comment: @KrishJacky help yourself first. When you get stuck then come back here and ask a question that isn't answered in every single objective-c book and tutorial website.

Comment: Sorry for this question.

Comment: This is the third time this question has been changed to a completely NEW question. Please, post a NEW question and don't change your old question every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really short explanation. I can point you in a direction at least.

**Subclass**
Inherit functions of a class. You want to have the same behaviour as the class you just subclassed but with some of your own custom functionality.

**Category**
Add extra functionality to a class that fits your needs. In other words you could add a method to a class (NSString for example) that lets you count the characters. This can later be called on your NSString class.

**Protocol**
You can delegate tasks to another class that has set itself as a delegate. You can force classes to implement certain methods.